# want to redirect webview to other intent when url loading has finished in webview android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, webview

**I want to redirect webview to another activity when url loading has
 completed. This is my code for webview :- this class is extended by webview**

```
   **   1)  This the method where I am doing code for redirecting webview to activity**
```

**> This is onPagefinished method where url is loading.**

```
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.endsWith("paymentconfirmation/"))
                    ((DibsPaymentScreen) getContext())
                            .setCancelDisallowed(false);
                if (callbackUrl.equals(url)
                        && statusCancelled.equals(paymentData.params
                                .get(statusKey))) {
                    paymentResultListener.cancelUrlLoaded();
                } else if (callbackUrl.equals(url)
                        && statusAccepted.equals(paymentData.params
                                .get(statusKey))) {
                    paymentResultListener.paymentAccepted(paymentData.params);

                } else if (!windowIsLoaded) {
                    paymentWindowLoaded();

                }

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                            if (url.equals("http://nmotion.dk/paymentconfirmation/")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),
                                RestaurantsListScreen.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you search? show code.

Comment: @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    if (url.equals("http://nmotion.dk/paymentconfirmation/")) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),
       RestaurantsListScreen.class);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     getContext().startActivity(intent);
     view.destroy();
     return true;

    }

    return false;
   }

Comment: I have posted the code here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to implement the on finish loader in the WebView WebViewCLient

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // create your intent here
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
});
```

EDITED WHIT SUPPLIED CODE

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   if (url.equals("http://nmotion.dk/paymentconfirmation/")) {

       Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), RestaurantsListScreen.class);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       getContext().startActivity(intent);

       return true;

   } else {
            if (url.endsWith("paymentconfirmation/")){
                ((DibsPaymentScreen) getContext()).setCancelDisallowed(false);
            }
            if (callbackUrl.equals(url) && statusCancelled.equals(paymentData.params.get(statusKey))) {
                paymentResultListener.cancelUrlLoaded();

            } else if (callbackUrl.equals(url)

               && statusAccepted.equals(paymentData.params.get(statusKey))) {
                paymentResultListener.paymentAccepted(paymentData.params);

            } else if (!windowIsLoaded) {
                paymentWindowLoaded();

            }

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
```

}

Comment: you have to move the intent in the OnPageFinished (check there if (url.equals("http://nmotion.dk/paymentconfirmation/")) ) because the shouldOverrideUrlLoading prevent the webview to load the url (it's fired before the loading)

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         if (url.endsWith("paymentconfirmation/"))
                ((DibsPaymentScreen) getContext())
                        .setCancelDisallowed(false);
            if (callbackUrl.equals(url)
                    && statusCancelled.equals(paymentData.params
                            .get(statusKey))) {
                paymentResultListener.cancelUrlLoaded();
            } else if (callbackUrl.equals(url)
                    && statusAccepted.equals(paymentData.params
                            .get(statusKey))) {
                paymentResultListener.paymentAccepted(paymentData.params);

            } else if (!windowIsLoaded) {
                paymentWindowLoaded();
            }

            if (url.equals("http://nmotion.dk/paymentconfirmation/")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),
                            RestaurantsListScreen.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    getContext().startActivity(intent);
                   }

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
});
```

Comment: in on finish method my other work is being performed.

Comment: why should not you call  

"if (url.equals("http://nmotion.dk/paymentconfirmation/")) { .... } "

before
 
"super.onPageFinished(view, url);"

Comment: with your code suggestion and ryoghurt code suggestions.

Comment: `super.onPageFinished(view, url);` is always first line of the method.